# Ajax not appending HttpResponse from Django

Tags: ajax, django

The aim of my program is to take input from html page, send it to Django so the text turns upper case, and return a response so the page can display the uppercased text. There is no update to the page.

**Code on the html:**

```
    <script>
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        val = $("#input").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'upper' %}",
            data: {'input':val},
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Django's views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", context = {"text": 'This is from Django'})


def upper(request):
    vals = request.GET.get('input')
    print(vals)
    return HttpResponse(vals.upper)
```

Comment: Should be just `return HttpResponse(vals)`

Comment: @Gasanov I'm trying to return an all caps version of the text.

Comment: then use `return HttpResponse(vals.upper())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `upper()` not upper only

Change`return HttpResponse(vals.upper)`

Change to :

```
return HttpResponse(vals.upper())
```

[See the official documentation for more details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)